# Python. Remove similar items with other extension from list

Tags: python, string, list, file, filesystems

I have a problem.
After this code working:

```
path, dirs, files = next(os.walk(f'：stories/'))
    print(files)
```

i have a list, containing different strings:

```
['2021-07-23_14-52-16_UTC.jpg', '2021-07-23_14-52-16_UTC.mp4',
 '2021-07-23_15-59-38_UTC.jpg', '2021-07-23_15-59-38_UTC.mp4',
 '2021-07-23_17-23-06_UTC.jpg', '2021-07-23_17-23-06_UTC.mp4',
 '2021-07-23_19-42-32_UTC.jpg', '2021-07-23_20-04-18_UTC.jpg',
 '2021-07-23_20-04-18_UTC.mp4', '2021-07-23_20-38-03_UTC.jpg',
 '2021-07-23_20-38-03_UTC.mp4', '2021-07-23_21-38-22_UTC.jpg',
 '2021-07-23_21-38-22_UTC.mp4', '2021-07-23_21-42-07_UTC.jpg',
 '2021-07-23_21-42-07_UTC.mp4', '2021-07-23_21-42-34_UTC.jpg',
 '2021-07-23_21-42-34_UTC.mp4', '2021-07-24_01-01-30_UTC.jpg',
 '2021-07-24_01-01-30_UTC.mp4', '2021-07-24_06-57-14_UTC.jpg',
 '2021-07-24_10-22-46_UTC.jpg', '2021-07-24_12-38-47_UTC.jpg',
 '2021-07-24_13-07-34_UTC.jpg']
```

Problem is: I need to remove .jpg files, if there is .mp4 file with the same name.

My solution was:

```
for _ in files:
    temp = _.replace('.mp4', '.jpg')
    if temp in files:
        os.remove(_)
```

but this part of code removes every file.

Can someone help me or tell, what my mistake is. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to indent os.remove(_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `replace()` may not actually change anything, so you're removing every file in the list. Try this:

```
for file in files:
    temp = _.replace('.mp4', '.jpg')
    if temp != file and temp in files:
        os.remove(file)
```

Comment: Try using `file` instead of `_` .

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
l=['2021-07-23_14-52-16_UTC.jpg', '2021-07-23_14-52-16_UTC.mp4',
 '2021-07-23_15-59-38_UTC.jpg', '2021-07-23_15-59-38_UTC.mp4',
 '2021-07-23_17-23-06_UTC.jpg', '2021-07-23_17-23-06_UTC.mp4',
 '2021-07-23_19-42-32_UTC.jpg', '2021-07-23_20-04-18_UTC.jpg',
 '2021-07-23_20-04-18_UTC.mp4', '2021-07-23_20-38-03_UTC.jpg',
 '2021-07-23_20-38-03_UTC.mp4', '2021-07-23_21-38-22_UTC.jpg',
 '2021-07-23_21-38-22_UTC.mp4', '2021-07-23_21-42-07_UTC.jpg',
 '2021-07-23_21-42-07_UTC.mp4', '2021-07-23_21-42-34_UTC.jpg',
 '2021-07-23_21-42-34_UTC.mp4', '2021-07-24_01-01-30_UTC.jpg',
 '2021-07-24_01-01-30_UTC.mp4', '2021-07-24_06-57-14_UTC.jpg',
 '2021-07-24_10-22-46_UTC.jpg', '2021-07-24_12-38-47_UTC.jpg',
 '2021-07-24_13-07-34_UTC.jpg']
for i in l[:]:
    if i.replace('.jpg','.mp4') in l:
        os.remove(i)
print(l)
```